# How to convert list of string to dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, web-scraping

I have a list of strings. I want to convert to dictionary. I got the output after scraping the data.

```
['Name:Dr. Mak', 'Location: India, Delhi']
['Name:Dr. Hus MD', 'Location:US, NY']
```

I want Output like below

```
{'Name':'Dr. Mak', 'Location': 'India, Delhi'}
{'Name':'Dr. Hus MD', 'Location':'US, NY'}
```

Comment: what did you try?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
dict(s.split(':', 1) for s in list_of_strings)
```

---

Edit: removing whitespace

```
dict(map(str.strip, s.split(':', 1)) for s in list_of_strings)
```

Comment: Thanks , its working

Comment: I think this good solution still lacks the str.strip() function applied to the values of the dict. I.e. sth like

dict([s.split(':')[0], s.split(':')[1].strip()] for s in list_of_strings)

Comment: It will fail if there is more than one colon in `s`, so `s.split(':', 1)` is safer.

Comment: @taras True, but I don't see why there would be a colon in a `country, city` schema

Comment: @FHTMitchell, well you never know:) Lets call it future-proof.